# Why does {{ site.eggs.label }} not return "eggs" for the jekyll collection "eggs"?

Tags: jekyll

config.yml defines collectio eggs

```
collections:
  eggs:
    output: true
```

A folder _eggs has a document with front matter

I can access the collection label so:

```
{{ site.collections[0].label }}
```

which returns "eggs" but not so

```
{{ site.eggs.label }}
```

which returns nothing as does this:

```
{{ site.eggs }}
```

The documentation about collections at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#liquid-attributes does not make much sense to me: "The collections are also available under site.collections, with the metadata you specified". In an issue at github the authors say, that the collections field was (silently?) dropped (https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4392).

I am currently evaluating Jekyll and this causes doubts where it stable, has up to date docs and has other pitfalls ahead.

Do I misunderstand the docs? Why does the above access to collection metadata not work.

Comment: Do you need to simply get the label of your collection? There's a solution in the linked issue, but I'm not sure if that's the correct answer. Also, is `{{ site.eggs }}` empty for you? That one should return all eggs.

Comment: it should return all eggs, but the output is empty. reading docs and the issues i dropped jekyll already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata of each collection is available with `site.collections`, that means, it will return an array of the collections with its metadata.

If one access a collection directly, like `site.eggs`, there won't be metadata available, but an array of all the collection files, i.e. all the files in the `_eggs` folder.

## example

To display the contents of `site.eggs` you can iterate over each file, consider having the following file in `/_eggs/item.yml`

```
---
title: "Jekyll is awesome"
---
```

Then you can display it in `/index.yml` like:

```
{% for egg in site.eggs %}
{{egg.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
Jekyll is awesome
```

Comment: that looks as i would expect it, but on my machine with a fresh installation, this simply did not word. the loop above did not render anything. but what you write at the beginning matches my findings: site.collections is an array, accessing metadata by name is then impossible, only by index or looping and lookup. thx

Comment: I've also tested it on a fresh installation, it should work for you too, what is the error or the contents of the eggs collection files you have?

Comment: nearly everything is nothing, empty, rendered as "". currently moved over to hugo, so cant investigate atm, but jekyll is still on my list now or later. thx for your time & help.